# Need a Return Ticket at Port of Entry?

Tags: tickets, canada, denial-of-entry

I have a tourist visa for Canada. Do I need a return ticket to be allowed entry, at the Port of Entry? I remember being asked for the return ticket at the PoE in USA. I didn't have a printout, and the officer was okay with it. How does it work with Canada? Seems like a simple enough question.

Comment: They will usually ask you for some proof you're leaving, but they may also not, it depends on the officer. In the past I've shown email confirmations on my phone and that was enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. I've entered it several times.  Inevitably I'm asked about my travel plans, and I explain my trip.  Sometimes they've asked how and when I'm leaving Canada. Only on two occasions have they asked to see evidence of said trip.

But they have asked, and have the right to ask.

In addition, many airlines will refuse to carry you to a country (eg Canada) if you don't have an exit ticket as well.

Simple solution if you don't have one yet - buy a refundable plane ticket, or a megabus/greyhound ticket from Vancouver to Seattle or Toronto to Buffalo.